# Foul Smell when turning on air conditioning

Tags: hvac, chrysler, smell

I have a 2007 Chrysler Aspen, and recently (past 2 weeks) when I turn on the ac, I notice a 'foul' smell, like burnt rubber, or even sulphur-like. The smell will last a few minutes and will gradually fade away while the ac is running. Since this has not happened to me before, I need to know if something is going on with the ac. I would appreciate any help or suggestions with this concern.

Comment: Just FYI: That title was terrible. A more descriptive title will help folks get you an answer that will clear up your issue ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the following answers.  They might be relevant to your situation:

[toyota corolla 2001 air duct smell](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1634/57)

[Heater smells like sulfur](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/730/57)

[Why does my A/C blow foul smelling air when it first turns on?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/116/57)

Here's a subset of [what I suggested for the "heater" question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/730/heater-smells-like-sulfur/747#747):

> Leaking gear lubrication (which can smell like sulfur) combined with a
>   bad seal in the ventilation system (or an intake that catches a
>   whiff). Check for drips under the car: they should have the same
>   smell. If they're there, look for leaks around the transmission or
>   differentials.
>
> Hydrogen sulfide from the catalytic converter, again getting picked up
>   by the ventilation system. If so, this is possibly a bad cat.

Hopefully, one or more of the above discussions will help you in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing cabin Filter and see if that makes difference if you have not changed lately. Generally Cabin Filter is under Gloves Compartment on Passenger Side

Comment: This would be my first guess as well. I once had a mouse find its way into the fan where this filter resides...poor little guy.